# jquery events defined in tag attributes (framework/library)

Tags: jquery, html, events, attributes, bind

I'm looking for Javascript library that implements automatic events binding through tag attribute. There is ixEdit project (discontinued since 2009).

Like ixEdit every event has three parts - event, action and optionaly condition.

```
 Event     : selector, name
 Action    : selector, function, params
 Condition : selector, function, params
```

Some tags will have attribute events="" and jquery process and bind all defined events.
Every action has function to handle, and optionaly can generate another event.

I make an example on jsFidle, to show what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/8dQwZ/

Is there any javascript library implementing similar functionality? Well, ixEdit stands on outdated google gears. Before i start development new library, i'd like use existing.

But rather than configuration via dialog (in ixEdit) i'm looking for development library, generating json server side, before rendering widget. No prepared actions like in ixEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I start development javascript library named jQents. Source code is available on github
http://github.com/opio/jqents

Any comments on architecture will be helpfull